# Ethernet Connections - How do I know the other side has reset and I need to close?

Tags: c#, .net

I open a connection and send data to a device. That is OK but when I test the device by sending garbage it tells me it is garbage then gets upset and resets the connection. My connection is still open so I send more data but it does nothing. I have worked out how to see when the network dies but I have not found a good way of know the other side has reset the connection.

I looked at using Ping but that gave too much overhead.
I tried sending a message asking for the device ID but again I have to send it before every send and that is also not so good on resources.

I have the connection in a class as I can have more than one connection to the different device even to the same port. Not sure if helpful but here is the connection function.

```
 public void Connect(string ipAddr, string port)
    {
        client = new Socket(AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
        IPEndPoint ipe = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Parse(ipAddr), Convert.ToInt32(port));
        client.Connect(ipe);

        clientListener = new Thread(OnDataReceived);
        isEndClientListener = false;
        clientListener.Start();
    }
```

Is there a command I can use? Has someone done this in a different way?

Comment: What is in `OnDataReceived`? If the connection is reset on the TCP level, you'll get an exception. If it is closed politely, `Socket.Receive` calls will return 0. If the other side keeps the connection open but simply refuses to talk, there's nothing you can do about that other than to `.Close` the socket yourself when you've been told you sent something bad, but that would be an unusual scenario.

Comment: OnDataReceive I am just listening for unsolicited data coming my way from the device. It also receives the answers to the questions I send the device. In Wireshark I see the device calls the RST but I do not know what it does my side as my connection remains open. Is there a flag I should be reading?

Comment: If an RST happens on the connection, the next active operation on the socket (be it `Send` or `Receive`) *will* abort and throw an exception. If you're not getting any, then either you're looking at the wrong socket (for example, because you've unwittingly replaced an instance field?) or an operation is not pending. In theory there could be other things gumming up the works, like some intermediate network layer mucking things up (software firewall or other filter driver) but this would be very unusual.